# How to execute multiple statements in a MATLAB anonymous function?

Tags: matlab, command-line, anonymous-function

I'd like to do something like this:

```
>> foo = @() functionCall1() functionCall2()
```

So that when I said:

```
>> foo()
```

It would execute `functionCall1()` and then execute `functionCall2()`.  (I feel that I need something like the [C , operator](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4db.html))

EDIT:

`functionCall1` and `functionCall2` are not necessarily functions that return values.

Comment: Do functionCall1 and functionCall2 ever have to accept input values? If not, the solution I gave below should work. If they do accept values, my solution could still work but would need some modification.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example for passing input arguments, just in case you need it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Trying to do everything via the command line without saving functions in m-files may be a complicated and messy endeavor, but here's one way I came up with...

First, make your [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) and put their [handles](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html) in a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html):

```
fcn1 = @() ...;
fcn2 = @() ...;
fcn3 = @() ...;
fcnArray = {fcn1 fcn2 fcn3};
```

...or, if you have functions already defined (like in m-files), place the function handles in a cell array like so:

```
fcnArray = {@fcn1 @fcn2 @fcn3};
```

Then you can make a new anonymous function that calls each function in the array using the built-in functions [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) and [`feval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/feval.html):

```
foo = @() cellfun(@feval,fcnArray);
```

Although funny-looking, it works.

**EDIT:** If the functions in `fcnArray` need to be called with input arguments, you would first have to make sure that ALL of the functions in the array require THE SAME number of inputs. In that case, the following example shows how to call the array of functions with one input argument each:

```
foo = @(x) cellfun(@feval,fcnArray,x);
inArgs = {1 'a' [1 2 3]};
foo(inArgs);  %# Passes 1 to fcn1, 'a' to fcn2, and [1 2 3] to fcn3
```

**WORD OF WARNING:** The documentation for [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) states that the *order* in which the output elements are computed is not specified and should not be relied upon. This means that there are no guarantees that `fcn1` gets evaluated before `fcn2` or `fcn3`. If order matters, the above solution shouldn't be used.

Comment: sweet! i've been trying to figure out something similar.

Comment: Interesting! And of course you could just declare fcnArray directly instead of as a separate variable, so something like:
`myfun = @() cellfun(@feval,{@() xlim([1 5]), @() xlabel('seconds')});`
Now, calling myfun will set both xlim and xlabel in the figure.

Answer (score 14):

The anonymous function syntax in Matlab (like some other languages) only allows a single expression.  Furthermore, it has different variable binding semantics (variables which are not in the argument list have their *values* lexically bound at function creation time, instead of references being bound).  This simplicity allows Mathworks to do some optimizations behind the scenes and avoid a lot of messy scoping and object lifetime issues when using them in scripts.

If you are defining this anonymous function within a function (not a script), you can create named inner functions.  Inner functions have normal lexical reference binding and allow arbitrary numbers of statements.

```
function F = createfcn(a,...)
  F = @myfunc;
  function b = myfunc(...)
    a = a+1; 
    b = a; 
  end
end
```

Sometimes you can get away with tricks like gnovice's suggestion.

Be careful about using eval... it's very inefficient (it bypasses the JIT), and Matlab's optimizer can get confused between variables and functions from the outer scope that are used inside the eval expression.  It's also hard to debug and/or extent code that uses eval.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a method that will guarantee execution order and, (with modifications mentioned at the end) allows passing different arguments to different functions.

```
call1 = @(a,b) a();
call12 = @(a,b) call1(b,call1(a,b));
```

The key is `call1` which calls its first argument and ignores its second. `call12` calls its first argument and then its second, returning the value from the second. It works because a function cannot be evaluated before its arguments. To create your example, you would write:

```
foo = @() call12(functionCall1, functionCall2);
```

**Test Code**

Here is the test code I used:

```
>> print1=@()fprintf('1\n');
>> print2=@()fprintf('2\n');
>> call12(print1,print2)
1
2
```

**Calling more functions**

To call 3 functions, you could write

```
call1(print3, call1(print2, call1(print1,print2)));
```

4 functions:

```
call1(print4, call1(print3, call1(print2, call1(print1,print2))));
```

For more functions, continue the nesting pattern.

**Passing Arguments**

If you need to pass arguments, you can write a version of `call1` that takes arguments and then make the obvious modification to `call12`.

```
call1arg1 = @(a,arg_a,b) a(arg_a);
call12arg1 = @(a, arg_a, b, arg_b) call1arg1(b, arg_b, call1arg1(a, arg_a, b))
```

You can also make versions of call1 that take multiple arguments and mix and match them as appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible, using the [curly](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/01/24/introduction-to-functional-programming-with-anonymous-functions-part-2/#eadbce51-e1cc-46e9-80ea-58f1108621fc) function which is used to create a comma separated list.

```
curly = @(x, varargin) x{varargin{:}};
f=@(x)curly({exp(x),log(x)})
[a,b]=f(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `functionCall1()` and `functionCall2()` return something and those somethings can be concatenated, then you can do this:

`>> foo = @() [functionCall1(), functionCall2()]`

or

`>> foo = @() [functionCall1(); functionCall2()]`

A side effect of this is that `foo()` will return the concatenation of whatever `functionCall1()` and `functionCall2()` return.

I don't know if the execution order of `functionCall1()` and `functionCall2()` is guaranteed.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I'm dealing with functions that don't return values.