# Merging function handles in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm currently coding a simulation in MATLAB and need some help in regards to an issue that I've been having.

I'm working on a problem where I have *n* separate anonymous function handles *f*<sub>*i*</sub> stored in cell array, each of which accepts a 1×1 numeric array *x*<sub>*i*</sub> and returns a 1×1 numeric array *y*<sub>*i*</sub>.

I'm trying to combine each of these anonymous function handles into a single anonymous function handle that accepts a single *n*×1 numeric array *X* and returns a single *n*×1 numeric array *Y*, where the *i*-th elements of *X* and *Y* are *x*<sub>*i*</sub> and *y*<sub>i</sub> = *f*<sub>*i*</sub> (*x*<sub>*i*</sub>), respectively.

As an example, let *n* = 2 and `f_1`, `f_2` be two function handles that input and output 1×1 arrays and are stored in a cell array named `functions`:

```
f_1 = @(x_1) x_1^2 
f_2 = @(x_2) x_2^3
functions = {f_1, f_2}
```

In this example, I basically need to be able to use `f_1` and `f_2` to construct a function handle `F` that inputs and outputs a 2×1 numeric array, like so:

```
F = @(x) [f_1(x(1,1)); f_2(x(2,1))]
```

The question is how to generalize this for an arbitrary number *n* of such functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is difficult to define such a function using the inline `@()`-anonymous
syntax (because of the requirement for the function’s body to be
an expression).

However, it is possible to define a regular function that runs over
the items of a given vector and applies the functions from a given
cell array to those items:

```matlab
function y = apply_funcs(f, x)
    assert(length(f) == length(x));
    y = x;
    for i = 1 : length(f)
        y(i) = feval(f{i}, x(i));
    end
end
```

If it is necessary to pass this function as an argument to another
one, just reference it by taking its `@`-handle:

```matlab
F = @apply_funcs
```

Comment: Thanks for this! 

I need the code to be efficient as possible, so I will probably use your function and remove the length/assert arguments... 

Also, would you happen to know whether feval is faster than using the inline function handle evaluation? That is to say, would y(i) = f{i}(x(i)) be faster than y(i) = feval(f{i},x(i))>

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved using [a solution I provided to a similar previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558478/how-to-execute-multiple-statements-in-a-matlab-anonymous-function/558868#558868), although there will be some differences regarding how you format the input arguments. You can achieve what you want using the functions [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html) and [FEVAL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/feval.html) to evaluate your anonymous functions in one line, and the function [NUM2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/num2cell.html) to convert your input vector to a cell array to be used by [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html):

```
f_1 = @(x_1) x_1^2;     %# First anonymous function
f_2 = @(x_2) x_2^3;     %# Second anonymous function
fcnArray = {f_1; f_2};  %# Cell array of function handles
F = @(x) cellfun(@feval,fcnArray(:),num2cell(x(:)));
```

Note that I used the name `fcnArray` for the cell array of function handles, since the name `functions` is already used for the built-in function [FUNCTIONS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/functions.html). The [colon operator `(:)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colon.html) is used to turn `fcnArray` and the input argument `x` into column vectors if they aren't already. This ensures that the output is a column vector.

And here are a few test cases:

```
>> F([2;2])

ans =

     4
     8

>> F([1;3])

ans =

     1
    27
```

Comment: Thank you for this again. Your approach is definitely more parsimonious, though I'm wondering whether it would perform faster than the for loop described by ib?

Comment: k I'll try both and see which is better - do you know of some kind of resource that illustrates best MATLAB practices? I'm always trying to make my code as efficient as possible, though since there are often 3-4 ways to do these things with the inbuilt functions on MATLAB, I'm having a hard time figuring out what is costly and what is not.

Answer (score 1):

```
#you can try 
f=@(x)[x(1)^2;x(2)^3]
>>f([1,2])
ans =
     1
     8
>>f([2,3])
ans =
     4
    27
```