# MATLAB equivalent to Java's {}

Tags: matlab

I'd like to know MATLAB's equivalent to Java's {} for delimiting code blocks.  It seems that it would be simple to find out such a thing, but it is hard to search {} on Google, so I turn to StackOverflow.  Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:** My goal is to define a multi-line anonymous function.

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? Local scope variables, code folding for easy editing?

Comment: Already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558478/how-to-execute-multiple-statements-in-a-matlab-anonymous-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ... to continue lines. So to make a multi-line anonymous function:

```
fun=@(x)(...
    x.^2+...
    x+...
    1);

fun(1:10)

ans =

 3     7    13    21    31    43    57    73    91   111
```

If on the other hand you want to have multiple statements in an anonymous function, it is not possible. See e.g. [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558478/how-to-execute-multiple-statements-in-a-matlab-anonymous-function).

Comment: lol, that actually is multi-line. But he meant anonymous function with serveral instructions (e.g x=2;y=3;z=x*y;).

Comment: @Oli well, I just answered the question :) Thats why I asked to make it more precise..

Answer (score 2):

You can define a sub-function in the same file to do that:

```
function y=foo()
  y=1;
  bar(y)
end

function z=bar(y)
  x=2*y; % x stays local
  z=2*x;
end
```

Comment: The problem with this on the other hand is that you can not define functions in simple scripts. That's why foo needs to be a function.