# What's the correct syntax to declare multiple line anonymous functions?

Tags: matlab

EDIT:

In regards to the linked question referenced above, I'm trying to describe a different computation than the one above. The one above is of form:

```
func1 >> func2 >> func3
```

where `>>` denotes continuation. Most importantly, func2 do not bind to any variable output by func1, and so on.

My function is of form:

```
func1 >>=@ x func2(x) >>=@ y func3(y)
```

where `>>=@` denotes continuation from func1 and func2, *and* func2 binds to the output of func1. So the key here is variable assignment needs to persist between function calls.

Question Proper.

I have this function declaration:

```
function[y] = distR3(x,c)
    a = bsxfun(@minus, x, reshape(c, [1 1 3]));
    b = a .* a;
    c = b(:,:,1) + b(:,:,2) + b(:,:,3);
    y = sqrt(c);
end
```

That I would like to convert to some anonymous function, perhaps like:

```
% Incorrect syntax
distRN = @(x,c) 
    a = bsxfun(@minus, x, reshape(c, [1 1 3]));
    b = a .* a;
    c = b(:,:,1) + b(:,:,2) + b(:,:,3);
    y = sqrt(c);
    return y
```

The key thing to note here is that there's multiple lines in the function, with variable assignment and possibly in-place update of variables.

Is such a thing possible?

EDIT EDIT:

I seem to have found an answer that uses "higher-order-functions". Here's the final code:

```
distRN = @(x,y) sqrt(c((b(a(x,y)))));
   a  = @(x,c) bsxfun(@minus, x, reshape(c, [1 1 3]));
   b  = @(a) a .* a;
   c  = @(b) b(:,:,1) + b(:,:,2) + b(:,:,3);
```

Note the indentations over a,b,and c are mine and have no effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute multiple statements in a MATLAB anonymous function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558478/how-to-execute-multiple-statements-in-a-matlab-anonymous-function)

Comment: I don't know it's the same thing since I need a variable assignment to persist between function calls, which is not explicitly stated in the question referenced.

Comment: State each variable assignment as an different anonymous function, as in the refered answer.

Comment: Though this may work, it is really ugly - what's the advantage of having a bunch of anonymous functions, if you could also use `@distR3` ?

Comment: It was just a matter of preference to put all my helper functions in one file if I know they won't have much use outside of the file at hand. But it turns out a,b,and c have to be declared above distRN on a fresh load of the file, so it would look extra non-sensical, sigh matlab