# Successive function application in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, functional-programming, anonymous-function, currying

How do I do successive function application in MATLAB with anonymous functions? Something like the following:

```
g = @(x) @(y) x+y;
g(1)(2)
```

However MATLAB gives an error at line 2: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.

But the following works:

```
g = @(x) @(y) x+y;
f = g(1);
f(2)
```

The script above outputs ans=3.

I am not very familiar with MATLAB but I think the ability to manipulate on the function level makes programming much easier. For example, when I need to compute projections of functions onto some subspace of L^2, the projection operator and normalization etc. all output functions that take additional arguments to evaluate to a numerical answer.

Comment: I don't think what you are describing is actually *currying*. Do want to know how to evaluate `g(1)(2)` or do you want to know how to do currying in MATLAB? (Which is generating a function `X -> (Y -> Z)` from a function `(X x Y) -> Z`)

Comment: @knedlsepp I would like to know the former, i.e. how to evaluate g(1)(2). Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute multiple statements in a MATLAB anonymous function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558478/how-to-execute-multiple-statements-in-a-matlab-anonymous-function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MATLAB doesn't support single expression calls like `y = g(1)(2)` to function handles returned by functions. You can however work your way around this limitation by using temporary variables:

```
g1 = g(1); 
y = g1(2);
```

As an alternative you could build your own function to wrap around this functionality.

A recursive approach could be:

```
function f = fevalIterated(f, varargin)
if ~isempty(varargin)
    f = fevalIterated(f(varargin{1}), varargin{2:end});
end
```

Instead of `y = g(1)(2)` you would call `y = fevalIterated(g, 1, 2)`.

The iterative approach to do this might be faster:

```
function f = fevalIterated(f, varargin)
for i = 1:numel(varargin)
    f = f(varargin{i});
end
```

As you were asking about the concept of currying in MATLAB, which is really similar to this:

### Un-currying

Un-currying would mean to convert a function `@(x) @(y) @(z) x+y+z` to a function `@(x,y,z) x+y+z`. This is a very similar concept and you can thus reuse the functionality of `fevalIterated` to build a function `uncurry` that can be used like this:

```
g = uncurry(@(x) @(y) @(z) x+y+z);
y = g(1,2,3)
```

The function `uncurry` would be defined as:

```
function uncurried = uncurry(f)
uncurried = @(varargin) fevalIterated(f, varargin{:});
```

### Currying

To curry a function `@(x,y,z) x+y+z` would mean to convert it to `@(x) @(y) @(z) x+y+z`.

Here is a recursive implementation of `curry`:

```
function f = curry(f,N)
if N>1
    f = @(first) curry(@(varargin)f(first,varargin{:}), N-1);
end
```

A (faster) iterative implementation would look like this:

```
function f = curry(f,N)
for i = 1:N-1
    f = @(varargin) @(last) f(varargin{:}, last);
end
```

You can call both via `f = curry(@(x,y,z) x+y+z, 3)`.

### Caveat

Although you can do all this in MATLAB, you might suffer from a noticable performance drop if you overdo the whole function handle calling thingy.

```
f = @(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11,x12,x13,x14,x15) ...
     (x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10+x11+x12+x13+x14+x15);
%%// Currying vs Comma separated list expansion
%// Comma separated list expansion
tic;
[C{1:15}] = deal(12345);
f(C{:});
toc;
%// Elapsed time is 0.000146 seconds.

%// Currying
g = curry(f,15);
tic;
for i = 1:15
    g = g(12345);
end
toc;
%// Elapsed time is 0.015679 seconds.
```

Comment: @DavidYao: I added a bit about currying. It might also be of interest to you.