# Matlab evaluate several functions at same point

Tags: matlab

I am saving coefficients from several regressions and would like to later evaluate all the different predicted values at once. This particular bit of code is going to be called a lot, so I would like this to be as fast and efficient as possible. 
The idea is that I have an object, where, say

```
    F{1} = @(x) 0.5 + 1*x
    F{2} = @(x) 0.3 + .4*x
```

Now I would like to evaluate e.g. F(5) and get 5.5 and 2.3 as my result without having to do F{1}(5) and F{2}(5).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to execute multiple statements in a MATLAB anonymous function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/558478/52738)

Answer (score 1):

Your two functions:

```
F{1} = @(x) 0.5 + 1*x;
F{2} = @(x) 0.3 + .4*x;

% create another anonymous function which calls both F{1} and F{2}
FF = @(x) [F{1}(x) F{2}(x)];

FF(5)
```

gives you the output:

```
[5.5 2.3]
```

**edit**

If you want something a bit more clever you could use a normal function for the "collection" which you can do a bit more with:

```
function test_function
  F{1} = @(x) 0.5 + 1*x;
  F{2} = @(x) 0.3 + .4*x;

  result = collectorFunction ( 5, F{:} )

end
function output = collectorFunction ( x, varargin )
  output = zeros(nargin-1,1);
  for ii=2:nargin
    output(ii-1) = feval(varargin{ii-1}, x );
  end
end
```

result

```
5.5
2.3
```

Then if you add another `F{3}` for example the collector function will automatically *collect* the results:

```
function test_function
  F{1} = @(x) 0.5 + 1*x;
  F{2} = @(x) 0.3 + .4*x;
  F{3} = @(x) 1.3 + .3*x;             % Simply ADD a new F{N}....

  result = collectorFunction ( 5, F{:} )

end
function output = collectorFunction ( x, varargin )
  output = zeros(nargin-1,1);
  for ii=2:nargin
    output(ii-1) = feval(varargin{ii-1}, x );
  end
end
```

result:

```
5.5
2.3
2.8
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I thought about that, and it's actually my current work-around. I just found that this is fairly slow to implement. Also, this can not easily handle varying numbers of inputs.

Comment: Updated to allow the *collection* to dynamically handle multiple functions