# How to set variable value with slider in GUI in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a GUI, there I have some sliders and I want to change the R4 variable from callback.
I tried this(also, it works on edit buttons, but not on sliders):

```
%Function file
Slider2 = uicontrol('Style','slide',...
                    'Units','normalized',...
                    'Position',[0.65 0.71 0.15 0.05],...
                    'Min',1,'Max',100,'Value',R4,...
                    'Callback',['R4=','num2str(get(Slider2,''Value''))']); %I tried 'str2num(get(gco,''String''))' too, doesn't work. It's throwing this error: Warning: 'slider' control requires a scalar Value. //I kinda understand what he tries to say, but i don't know how to do it.
%display the value of the slider
uicontrol('Style','text',...
          'Units','normalized',...
          'BackgroundColor',[0.75,0.75,0.75],...
          'Position',[0.80 0.70 0.05 0.05],...
          'foregroundcolor','black',...
          'String',num2str(get(Slider2,'Value')));
```

And the edit button:

```
uicontrol('Style','text',...
                    'Units','normalized',...
                    'BackgroundColor',[0.75,0.75,0.75],...
                    'ForegroundColor','black',...
                    'Position',[0.10 0.8 0.05 0.05],...
                    'String','R1 =');
ButEd1 = uicontrol('Style','edit',...
                    'Units','normalized',...
                    'BackgroundColor',[0.75,0.75,0.75],...
                    'ForegroundColor','black',...
                    'Position',[0.15 0.81 0.1 0.05],...
                    'String',R1,...
                    'Callback',['R1=','str2num(get(gco,''String''))']);
```

Comment: Do you mean that the string in the text widget won't change when you interact with the slider?

Comment: What Matlab version are you using? Did you try to use the AppDesigner App to create your GUI? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples.html?category=app-designer&s_tid=CRUX_topnav

Comment: @MarcoTorres I can't use AppDesigner App. The university is forcing me to work how the teacher want.

Comment: @ShaobinJiang No. I don't know how to explain, but i'll give you an example. I made a button that recalls the function. Let's say i want to use that slider like a potentiometer. I want to change the resistance value and is not important to change the value live. But i have to get variable value from sliders using the GUI. When the value is where i want, i press the reset button and is shown in plot the capacitor saturation curve, less said, a graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: now updates and displays variable value as well. It's indeed a bit tricky, you can find some helpful explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558478/how-to-execute-multiple-statements-in-a-matlab-anonymous-function). How far-fetched is your homework supposed to be?

```
figure();
text=uicontrol('Style','text',...
          'Units','normalized',...
          'BackgroundColor',[0.75,0.75,0.75],...
          'Position',[0.80 0.70 0.05 0.05],...
          'foregroundcolor','black',...
          'String','50');
R4=[];
update_text=@(x) set(text,'String',num2str(x));
update_var=@(x) assignin('base','R4',x);
disp_var=@(x) disp(x);
update_all=@(x) cellfun(@feval,{update_text,update_var,disp_var},x);
update_call=@(x,y,z) update_all({x.Value,x.Value,x.Value});

Slider2 = uicontrol('Style','slide',...
                    'Units','normalized',...
                    'Position',[0.65 0.71 0.15 0.05],...
                    'Min',1,'Max',100,'Value',50,...
                    'Callback',update_call);
```

=========original post===========

You should have found in the [document](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/creating_guis/add-code-for-components-in-callbacks.html?lang=en) (search for 'Slider') that the callback function is expected to receive 3 parameters, with the first being the calling object (i.e. 'self'). Things are pretty straight-forward from there.

```
figure();
text=uicontrol('Style','text',...
          'Units','normalized',...
          'BackgroundColor',[0.75,0.75,0.75],...
          'Position',[0.80 0.70 0.05 0.05],...
          'foregroundcolor','black',...
          'String','50');

update_text=@(x,y,z) set(text,'String',num2str(x.Value));

Slider2 = uicontrol('Style','slide',...
                    'Units','normalized',...
                    'Position',[0.65 0.71 0.15 0.05],...
                    'Min',1,'Max',100,'Value',50,...
                    'Callback',update_text);
```

Comment: The teacher said we can use in a callback form return value. That is stuck in my head. Like, i used that callback on edit buttons, so i though i can use that simple form too on sliders. Is there a other way to use it just in callback? Or i need to do that? (What you gave me there, isn't helping me. I don't have a problem for showing the value. I need to change the value for a variable. But i can use set(R4,'Value', x.Value);?)

Comment: @AmicuLL I updated the code to meet your requirement. It is indeed a bit tricky. Do you have to contain everything within one single script?

Comment: I used your code and forgot to thank you. I can't get it why is such a complicated thing to get a value from sliders. Why you can't get the value with a basic callback how is done on variables. Maybe i'll figure it out sometime why is done in that way. Anyway, it doesn't matter, at leas for now. Thanks again, you're a legend!